# MagicalRecord - no contextDidSaveNotification when using saveWithBlock

Tags: ios, core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext, magicalrecord

This works, but MR_contextForCurrentThread is deprecated:

```
//    context = [NSManagedObjectContext MR_contextForCurrentThread];
//    
//    [context MR_saveToPersistentStoreWithCompletion:^(BOOL success, NSError* error) {
//        
//    }];
```

When I use the below, I don't get any contextDidSaveNotification notifications:

```
[MagicalRecord saveWithBlock:^(NSManagedObjectContext *localContext) {

    }];
```

I'm using version 2.3. Is this a bug or do I need to do something else to get the notifications?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This block is not setup to let you subscribe to change notifications. You should simply create a new context on your background thread and use your old save method:

```
context = [NSManagedObjectContext MR_context];

[context MR_saveToPersistentStoreWithCompletion:...];
```